# Image resize while using JQuery Reflection (jsfiddle)

Tags: jquery

I am trying to use the JQuery reflection function and I am running into some trouble. The reflection feature works fine on any image I try to add the class to, however, it works only if I do not modify the size of the image.

Once I try to resize the image that I am applying a reflection to, the size I try to apply to it is neglected and some of the image is cut off... I was wondering what is the correct way to resize an image that I am applying a reflection to?

jsFiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/suxcd/

**Note:** If you remove "width:50%" the reflection works fine, and the entire image displays as it should.

Comment: could of used a smaller image lol

Comment: Unfortunately, while googling images, the above image was the smallest I could find.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible, but it only works when using one percentual value for all images that you use reflect on (or you have to use ID's).

Anyway, here is the [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/suxcd/2/).

Most important code: edited the document ready code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var options = {
        opacity: 0.75
    };
    $('.reflect').reflect(options);
    $('.reflected').parent('.reflect').children('canvas').width('50%');
});​
```

Answer (score 1):

You are resizing by percentage, if you use a defined number it works

http://jsfiddle.net/suxcd/1/

I guess the question is do you need it to be in %

Edit:

see here http://jsfiddle.net/suxcd/3/

basically, I changed this

```
h.scale(0.5, -1);
```

0.5 same as 50%, you can set the 0.5 to a dynamic value easily. Get the width attribute on the img tag and if there is a % then grab the number convert it to decimal and use it there. If no % then don't change that

Comment: I didn't try giving the image size a rigid value because I need to use percentages for my project, but its good to know. thanks for the info.

Comment: @MHZ I have edited my answer so you can use percent on the img tag and it should work with different percentage values for different images. I provided the logic, the code isn't hard with jquery. You can also apply the same logic to the answer that you selected best answer for, so that you can use different percent sizes for any image